# Concatenate string number to start of series index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series:

```
ser = pd.Series(["foo","bar","a",4,5], index=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
ser

a    foo
b    bar
c      a
d      4
e      5
dtype: object
```

I want to concatenate an incrementing string number before the index as follows:

#desired output

```
0_a    foo
1_b    bar
2_c      a
3_d      4
4_e      5
dtype: object
```

I tried this:

```
increment = iter(range(0,10))

ser.index = str(next(increment))+"_"+ser.index
```

but the string number doesn't increment.  How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `f-string`s and `enumerate`:

```
ser.index = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in enumerate(ser.index)]
```

Or join `RangeIndex` converted to strings with [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
ser.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(ser)).astype(str).str.cat(ser.index, sep='_')
```

Or:

```
ser.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(ser)).astype(str) + '_' + ser.index
```

---

```
print (ser)
0_a    foo
1_b    bar
2_c      a
3_d      4
4_e      5
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ser.index.map(lambda x : str(next(increment))+x)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer is a great guide on how to answer a question.  putting in a bit of explanation would be great to see if this is generally an applicable answer.